# How can I measure RPM of an encased refrigerator compressor. I would like the resultant RPM reading as a variable DC output

Tags: measurements, vibration

I understand that there are very expensive meters that do this
; ex: Ono Sokki FT-7200 or FLuke, but I need a cheaper alternative.

Comment: I do not know enough about it to explain it in full but I think that "Back EMF" would be the right place to look. Essentially you would look at disturbances to the supply voltage.

Comment: use a microphone ... download Audacity ... https://www.audacityteam.org/

Comment: @jsotola, brilliant! -NN

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the reading, it may be possible to do this with your mobile phone running the audio spectrum [analyzer app](https://www.google.com/search?q=real%20time%20spectru%2C%20analyzer%20android&oq=real%20time%20spectru%2C%20analyzer%20android&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160l3.15263j1j7&client=tablet-android-samsung-nf-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#ip=1). The rotation frequency is likely to be between dominant frequencies of vibration.

If you are building some electronic device, some [frequency to voltage](https://www.google.com/search?q=frequency%20to%20voltage%20converter%20module&oq=frequency%20to%20voltage&aqs=chrome.2.0i512j69i57j0i512l6.10916j1j7&client=tablet-android-samsung-nf-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) converter may work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to open the motor casing, and if the armature has a nut on it then magnetize the nut.

That can then be tracked by a hall effect sensor and from that you can calculate the rpm.

Seen it used to measure the speed of a turbo charger shaft.